# Flink - External Checkpoints on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-flink, rocksdb, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I plan to use Flink on AWS Kinesis Analytics for Java Applications to perform stateful streaming aggregation.

I'd like to save checkpoints to a persistent store. What are my options?

- Can I use S3 using FsStateBackend?
- What about RocksSB? Is RocksDB offered our of the box by AWS Kineses Analytics for Java Applications?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding Flink checkpointing in Kinesis Data Analytics for Java Applications, [this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/java/how-fault.html) shows how to configure checkpointing to S3 bucket. Seems like S3 is the persistent store recommended by AWS.

You can see that `FsStateBackend` supports S3 in [Flink's official docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/filesystems/s3.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Michael. Do you know if AWS also supports checkpointing to RocksDB?

Comment: I'm sure you can checkpoint to RocksDB on AWS. However, I don't know if RocksDB is offered out of the box by AWS Kineses Analytics for Java Applications. Why not S3? It seems well-documented and will probably cost less.

Comment: According to the latest [Amazon Kinesis Data Analytics Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/java/reference-flink-settings.title.html) RocksDB is the default state backend and setting a different backend with `setStateBackend` has no effect.
I assume RocksDB saves by default on S3 but this is hidden from the user.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use FsStateBackend to store Flink's checkpoints in the s3 bucket which is recommended in Flink's [official document](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/ops/filesystems/s3.html).

*Please find a detailed working answer which I have provided* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64226597/apache-flink-to-use-s3-for-backend-state-and-checkpoints/64226598#64226598).

Comment: Kinesis Data Analytics always uses the RocksDBStateBackend. Using the FsStateBackend is not an option.